# How can I concat 2 different numbers to look like a decimal but is actually a varchar without losing place in the decimal portion?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate Hours and Minutes, but the minutes portion is dropping the leading 0 and it appears the calculation is incorrect.

Example, 9.06 is displaying as 9.6 using this query against the values

ClockIn   2020-01-07 23:00:53.000
ClockOut  2020-01-08 07:06:52.000

This results in a calculated time of 8.6:

```
concat(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60,'.',
    case when len(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut) - ((datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60) * 60)) = 1 
        then concat(0,cast(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut) - ((datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60) * 60)as varchar(2)))
        else datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut) - ((datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60) * 60)
    end 
)
```

Comment: You might want to simplify your question to focus on the specific expression that you have problems with, so it is easier to understand. A database tag (sqlserver ?) would be useful too.

Comment: If you provide sample data of `ClockIn` and `ClockOut` others can run your code script to better help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final version that works is as follows:

```
concat(cast(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60 as varchar(2)),'.',
    case when len(cast(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut) - ((datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60) * 60)as varchar(2))) = 1 
    then concat(0,cast(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut) - ((datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60) * 60)as varchar(2)))
    else cast(datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut) - ((datediff(n,ClockIn,ClockOut)/60) * 60) as varchar(2))
    end )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're making like so complicated for yourself. The [DATEDIFF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) function will give you both the hours and minutes depending on the first argument to the function:

```
SELECT 
concat(thehours,'.',
DATEDIFF(minute, '2017/08/25 07:00', '2017/08/25 12:45')-(60*thehours)) AS timediff
FROM (
  SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2017/08/25 07:00', '2017/08/25 12:45') AS thehours
) a
```

Comment: I tried your function using my example times, I still get 8.6

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to an appropriate string by taking the difference, creating a date/time, converting to a time and then to a string.

For example:

```
select convert(varchar(255), convert(time, dateadd(second, datediff(second, getdate(), getdate() + 0.001), 0)))
```

You can then remove the hour portion by using `stuff(X, 1, 3, '')`.

This might have some nuances to get the decimal places, but this give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

1) For a difference of less than 24 Hours you can use below:

```
DECLARE @ClockIn datetime = '2020-01-07 23:00:53.000',
        @ClockOut  datetime = '2020-01-08 07:06:52.000'

SELECT CAST(@ClockOut - @ClockIn as Time) As TimeDifference
```

2) For a difference of more than 24 hours but less than 12 months.

```
 DECLARE @ClockIn DATETIME = '2020-01-07 23:00:53.000',
        @ClockOut DATETIME = '2020-01-08 07:06:52.000'
SELECT 
     RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @ClockIn,@ClockOut) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @ClockIn,@ClockOut) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @ClockIn,@ClockOut) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

For more than 12 months, increase the varchar size. Your query should change to VARCHAR(4)),4 and so on, something like this should work

```
DECLARE @ClockIn DATETIME = '2019-01-07 23:00:53.000',
        @ClockOut DATETIME = '2020-01-08 07:06:52.000'
SELECT 
     RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @ClockIn,@ClockOut) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @ClockIn,@ClockOut) % 3600/60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + ':'
   + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEDIFF(S, @ClockIn,@ClockOut) % 60 AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
```

Comment: It doesn't give me exactly what I asked, but it helps me see how I can fix this.  Thanks to all who answered.